# Create mysql date range

Tags: mysql, date

Can't seem to find the answer I am looking for.

I want to create a range of dates from 2010-11-01 to 2015-01-01 in a table.

2010-11-01
2010-11-02
2010-11-03
etc...

Column datatype is 'Date'

Thanks

Comment: please see the answer I posted.

Comment: it's possible without using procedure, see here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS datespopulate;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE datespopulate(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN
  WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
    INSERT INTO datetable (d) VALUES (dateStart);
    SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
CALL datespopulate('2010-11-01','2015-01-01');
```

Note I named my table "`datetable`" and the column is named "`d`", but feel free to change this. Works fine on my end, let me know if you run in to an issue.

Kudos to Joe for getting the ball rolling. ;-)

Comment: @Joe: Not a problem, glad to help! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly take the brute force approach.

```
set @d = cast('2010-11-01' as date);

while (@d < '2015-01-02') do
    insert into YourTable 
        (YourColumn)
        values
        (@d);

    set @d = date_add(@d, interval 1 day);
end while;
```

Comment: @Joe: `DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements. ` (per [DECLARE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) -- think it needs to be a procedure, though you're on the right track)

Comment: @Joe: I still get a syntax error at the while condition. Does this work on your end?

Comment: @Brad: I don't have a place to test at this time. As you indicated earlier, this may need to be encapsulated in a proc.

Comment: @Joe/@mrlayance: I'm working on it. I stopped once this answer was posted, but I'll play around and see if I can bypass that error.

Answer (score 0):

Realize that this is an old thread- However, I found it useful and would like to suggest adding SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 to Brad's procedure. This will seriously increase the performance (On my system; from 2 hours to 4 seconds). More information is found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-transaction-management.html

Answer (score 0):

With the new SEQUENCE engine in MariaDB, there is a possibility:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_ADD(
        CAST('2022-06-01' AS DATE), 
        INTERVAL `s1`.`seq` DAY
    ) AS `dates` 
FROM `seq_0_to_364` AS `s1`;
```