# Determining free timeslots based on two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, calendar, timeslots

So I have two tables.

Table 1 is named 'appointment' with the following fields: `ID` (int), `TimeboxID` (int), `Date` (date)

Table 2 is named 'timebox' with the following fields: `ID` (int), `Weekday` (int), `StartTime` (varchar)

Table 1 keeps all appointments (`Date` + `TimeboxID` combo), while table 2 defines which timeslots are available for each day of the week.

Here's my question: How can I find out, in 1 query, which dates have free timeslots available (and how many)?

ps. Field `StartTime` is only needed for display, it has no meaning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use somthing like:

```
SELECT workdays.date, COUNT(DISTINCT timebox.ID) AS FreeTimeBoxes
FROM workdays
LEFT JOIN timebox ON (WEEKDAY(workdays.date) = timebox.Weekday)
LEFT JOIN appointment ON (workdays.date = appointment.date AND timebox.ID = appointment.TimeboxID)
WHERE appointment.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY workdays.date
```

Don't know if you replace the table workdays whit something automated

Comment: Thanks. I combined this with this [solution to populate the workdays table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736690/create-mysql-date-range)